# Conditional INSERT INTO for Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use Postgres 12 and I have two tables `users u` and `sessions s` with the following columns `s.user_id (FK) ==> u.user_id`.

I would like to insert a session, in case the password is correct and I found this type of statement:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (c1, c2, c3)
SELECT ??? FROM sessions
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
          SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.pwsha256 = "1234..."
    )
LIMIT 1;
```

This looks promising, but how would I bring over `u.user_id` from `users` to the `INSERT INTO` to reference them? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please post full table structure of `users` and `sessions` table. this will help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not only verify the password, but also check that the username is correct:

```
INSERT INTO sessions
   (user_id, ...)
VALUES (
   (SELECT id FROM users
    WHERE username = '...'
      AND users.pwsha256 = '1234...'),
   ...);
```